# rails drop down search/filter with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, rubygems, ransack

I have column with 3 set possibilities, say (fruit, veg, meat). I want to filter my rows with a drop down, so it only shows rows with fruits or veg etc. I have been looking at the ransack gem but all the examples make you type something into a text field. I plan to have several drop downs as will to filter other columns. Is ransack even the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can go for ransack

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :poollength_eq, options_for_poollength, {:include_blank => "Select Pool Length"}, {:style => "width:175px", class: "form-control"} %>
```

I defined options_for_poollength in the application_helper.rb as

```
def options_for_poollength
  [['Long Course Meters','LCM'], ['Short Course Yards','SCY'], ['Short Course Meter','SCM']]
end
```